# How can I create "meta" models using my existing DBIx::Class::Schema setup?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I have a bunch of tables mapped to ->resultset('User') and 'Tag' etc

How can I create resultset classes for querying across multiple resultset classes?

Comment: It might help to give an example of the type of query you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add (pseudo-code)–

```
 $self->search_related(foreign)->search_related(original);

 $self->search_related(foreign)
  ->search_related(many_to_many_foreign)
  ->search_related(foreign)
  ->search_related(original);
```

–style chains to resultset classes. This allows you to correlate/collect related data—with or without arguments—while returning a resultset of the original type. The following links give some excellent guidance. XUL isn't supported much of anywhere anymore but the plain text source is easy to read as “slides.” Some of the examples speak directly to what you’re after.

- [DBIx:Class Masterclass XUL slides](http://www.shadowcat.co.uk/catalyst/-talks/yapc-na-2008/dbix-masterclass.xul)
- [Somewhat crummy video of slide presentation](http://www.shadowcat.co.uk/archive/conference-video/yapc-eu-2008/dbic-masterclass/)

Answer (score 0):

So, it sounds like you basically want to create a virtual view (joining your tables, etc) right?

Check out [DBIx::Class::ResultSource::View](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aResultSource%3a%3aView) if so.  It'll allow you to create a virtual view resultsource, that can then be expressed through a resultset.